# MPLAB using external scientific library

Tags: c, gcc, mplab

I am using microcontroller from microchip and I am using MPLAB as my IDE tool. Now I would like to solve matrix problem called eigenvalues and eigenvectors of non symmetric 6x6 and 3x3 matrix. Based on [this wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#C) article I have quite an option choosing scientific libraries based on C code.

MPLAB has it's own gcc compiler called xc32-gcc for 32bit microcontrollers.
I choose [GNU-GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) library, and I did successfully solve the problem on my Ubuntu 14.04, but I need to do the same on my microcontroller. The question would be how can I compile and use this library with MPLAB.

Is there an easy way to do this or any other peace of C code being able to solve eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Also xc32 compiler is using c98 standard, so complex numbers has to be manually calculated.